# Is the KeyboardEvents mixin supposed to show keyboard automatically?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flame

I am building a Wordle game in Flutter and planning to show the on-screen input keyboard. I tried the following

```
class WordleGame extends FlameGame with KeyboardEvents {
  KeyEventResult onKeyEvent(
    RawKeyEvent event,
    Set<LogicalKeyboardKey> keysPressed,
  ) {}
}
```

but the keyboard is not showing up? Is this the right behavior? How can I show the keyboard for the duration of the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the keyboard is not showing up? Is this the right behavior?

Yes, The `KeyboardEvents` mixin doesn't handle the virtual keyboard on phones and such, it just handles the events that are triggered when a key is pressed (either on a virtual keyboard or a real one).

> How can I show the keyboard for the duration of the game?

To open the virtual keyboard I think you'll have to have a `TextField` widget or similar (it doesn't have to be visible).